# android.view.View, android.widget.TextView equivalent in androidx

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to write the codes listed here
[image]

I am using the newwest library of androidx, hence the first import becomes: `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`

I am wondering what would be the equivalent for the two other imports in `androidx`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AndroidX only replaces classes from the support library. `View` and `TextView` are not part of that, so there are no equivalents for that. Note that RecyclerView has `android.support` in the package name before migrating to AndroidX

Comment: thanks for the response, should I use the same android.view.View and android.widget.TextView then? Are these outdated?

Comment: you should just use them, they are not outdated

Answer (score 1):

`View` and `TextView` kept the same package name because they don't belong to the old support library.

If you were using `TextViewCompat` then it would be affected.

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) to check out the class mappings from support -> androidX.

Answer (score 0):

just open the xml file and start type textview or redesign the textview on the design tab.. and for View, delete the import and then hover on View code and then click alt+enter or ctrl+enter i forgot